How can I straighten this tree? (Golden Hearts Red Bud)
This tree was badly hurt by a fence that fell over it.
The tree was bent down to the soil but it survived and in that very spring had buds and normal leaves. I did use some rope and stakes to straighten it as you can see in the pictures but there is this mid segment just above the ground that is still bent (just below where the rope is tied to the trunk), Most of the trees like it and that I have seen have a very straight trunk.
The other question that I have is this: due to the incident above mentioned it seems that some fibers cracked and the tree core became visible in time ...it is now growing new bark as you can see in the second picture. Is there anything that I have to do to make sure that it does not impact the tree in the future ?
PS: yes the fence is still artificially supported one Y later and it was not replaced yet because I am waiting for my neighbor to move on this. all his tree sides are in that shape or worse and he has to find a contractor to do it (and probably the money :-) )



depending on how soft the trunk still is, you might be able to straigten it.
layout a tarp and some cable across the surface needing the most straightening.

then tie and anchor the tarp by tension via coil anchor facets into the ground


I don't think that I need anchors -the fence is close I can use that
I still don't see how this will fix it. There is a a bent like a bow there in the trunk so I guess I would need to push the middle of the bow in the opposite direction to the one I would pull its end toward ...the above does not seem to work that way. something like this https://i.imgur.com/m1rA8sy.png
